# Stable Matching with Ties

Tags: algorithm, matching, game-theory

Suppose we have a house assignment problem where agents all start off without endowments.  Now, the houses can have priorities (which we will treat like preferences) over the agents (for example, public housing may be allocated based on predefined criteria). There may be ties in the priorities the houses have over agents.

First, consider the agent-proposing Gale Shapley algorithm, with the extension that a house will dump someone it is engaged to if it gets a proposal from an agent for which it has either strictly higher or equal priority. Consider the following preferences (a denotes an agent and h a house). a1 ranks h2>h1>h3. a2 and h3 both rank 1>2>3. h1 has the same priorities for each agent a1∼a2∼a3, h2’s ranking is a2>a1>a3, and h3’s is a3>a1>a2.

Show that the agent-proposing Gale Shapley algorithm may lead to an outcome that is not agent-optimal (you can choose the order of proposals).

**Above is a problem that I was given.  I answered that a possible outcome that was not agent optimal was {a1, h3}, {a2, h2}, and {a3, h1}.**

**My reasoning:** Since both a1 and a2 would both prefer to be with h1 and h1 would be willing to accept that match this would mean there is at least one other weakly stable matching that one of the agents prefers to its current one. So it must not be agent optimal.

However, this was marked incorrect and I can't get any feedback on why.

Answer (score -1):

According to the posted criteria, your proposed solution isn't stable.

`h3` would definitely prefer to be with a3; `h1` doesn't care who it gets, and will switch at any suggestion.  They will switch agents.

**UPDATE PER OP COMMENTS**

Yes, the 1-1 2-2 3-3 solution is weakly stable -- no set of couples will agree to a switch.  However, it's weakly stable because a1 and a2 would switch, if given the chance.  This is typical of the "matching problem".

As your problem is written, *strict* preference is not required: houses willingly switch for any "strictly higher or equal priority".  In particular, h1 *will* switch if any other house proposes a swap.

Comment: So I think the problem is my application of the algorithm was originally incorrect. So if I got a solution where (a1, h1), (a2, h2), (a3, h3) then this would be weakly stable and my reasoning about why it is not agent optimal would be correct?

Comment: Also, in order for them to switch wouldn't a3 have to prefer h3 over his current assignment of h1?  For it to be unstable then some pair of a and h would have to strictly prefer each other over their current matching right?

Comment: What's the rationale for the down-vote?  If I'm wrong, I appreciate a correct.